# How to combine two lines together using Perl?

Tags: perl

How to combine two lines together using Perl? I'm trying to combine these two lines using a Perl regular expression:

```
__Data__
test1 - results
dkdkdkdkdkd
```

I would like the output to be like this:

```
__Data__
test1 - results dkdkdkdkdkd
```

I thought this would accomplish this but not working:

```
$_ =~ s/__Data__\n(test1.*)\n(.*)\n/__Data__\n$1 $2/smg;
```

Comment: How are you reading the lines?  Does `$_` actually contain all three lines when you apply the regex to it?  Show your code; it should only be a few lines.

Comment: I have the $/ commented out, like this # $/, I'm not reading it in as a Data record

Comment: Yes it contains all three because I see the output unchanged using print $_;

Comment: Did you `chomp` the input, perchance?  See my 'working solution', which uses almost exactly your regex.  I believe your problem is in what is in `$_`; it probably doesn't contain exactly what you think it contains.

Comment: @YetimworkBeyene I recommend using [`Data::Dumper`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data::Dumper) to print your data when debugging, e.g. `print Dumper $_`. Setting `$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1` will also show whitespace, which is useful in this case.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a multiline string:

```
s/__Data__\ntest1.*\K\n//g;
```

The `/s` modifier only makes the wildcard `.` match `\n`, so it will cause `.*` to slurp your newline and cause the match of `\n` to be displaced to the last place it occurs. Which, depending on your data, might be far off.

The `/m` modifier makes `^` and `$` match inside the string at newlines, so not so useful. The `\K` escape preserves whatever comes before it, so you do not need to put it back afterwards.

If you have a single line string, for instance in a while loop:

```
while (<>) {
    if (/^__Data__/) {
        $_ .= <>;  # add next line
        chomp;     # remove newline
        $_ .= <>;  # add third line
    }
    print;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a problem with the setup of `$_`.  When I run this script, I get the output I expect (and the output I think you'd expect).  The main difference is that I've added a newline at the end of the replacement pattern in the substitute.  The rest is cosmetic or test infrastructure.

#### Script

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $text = "__Data__\ntest1 - results\ndkdkdkdkdkd\n";
my $copy = $text;

$text =~ s/__Data__\n(test1.*)\n(.*)\n/__Data__\n$1 $2\n/smg;

print "<<$copy>>\n";
print "<<$text>>\n";
```

#### Output

```
<<__Data__
test1 - results
dkdkdkdkdkd
>>
<<__Data__
test1 - results dkdkdkdkdkd
>>
```

Note the use of `<<` and `>>` to mark the ends of strings; it often helps when debugging.  Use any symbols you like; just enclose your displayed text in such markers to help yourself debug what's going on.

(Tested with Perl 5.12.1 on RHEL 5 for x86/64, but I don't think the code is version or platform dependent.)

Comment: Try it with more lines in the string... the `/s` modifier will cause `.*` to find the last two newlines in the string.

Comment: Yes, the greedy `.*` can cause problems, but since the OP has not specified what is really in his input, I've shown what works for what might be supposed to be his input.  There are lots of things that can be done to improve the regex; the question is which ones are worthwhile, and without more knowledge of the situation, we don't know.